# How to reference Javascript files from assets fold in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cdn

I need to use the CDN setting for publicPath in Nuxt.js.
I've tried many different methods but they all failed. I'm not sure how you guys set it up correctly.

Thanks a lot.

I tried:

```
script: [{ src: '~/assets/js/assettwo.js' }]
```

```
script: [{ src: '~assets/js/assettwo.js' }]
```

```
script: [{ src: require('~/assets/js/assettwo.js') }]
```

```
head: {
    script: [
      { src: '~/assets/js/assettwo.js', ssr: false, body: true }
    ]
  },
```

```
 head: {
    script: [
      { src: require('~/assets/js/assettwo.js'), ssr: false, body: true }
    ]
  },
```